# It is possible to render layers sequentially?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, render-layers

If i have 3 layers of animation, same camera, but different objects, can i render them sequentially without having to doing it manually between processes? i ask this because i need to do this, but sometimes i won't be near the computer so it's important for me to acomplish this.
If i try to render them separately, every single sequence takes a lot of time so i should be near the computer after every process, the thing is that if i am not near the computer when one render finish, i will just lose time between renders.

Comment: yes, with python ;)

Answer (score 0):

Youn can go to the compositor, add 2 layer nodes and 2 file output nodes.

The standard Composite node will refer to the standard output file path which is set in the properties panel, while in the new output nodes you can set two different output file paths.

Every layer will be rendered in one go.

[image]